# Get a sublist by class in Java

Tags: java, list, generics, subclass

Suppose I have an

```
ArrayList<Fruit>
```

I would like to get all elements from this list of any given subclass of Fruit, such as an

```
ArrayList<Apple>
```

C# seems to have a rather handy

```
OfType<T>()
```

method. Is there an equivalent way of doing this in Java?

Cheers

Comment: JavaSE doesn't have it. I suggest writing the three lines of code that do this for you.

Comment: How would you write this in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static <T> Collection<T> ofType(Collection<? super T> col, Class<T> type) {
  final List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (Object o : col) if (type.isInstance(o)) ret.add((T)o);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work. I get an unchecked cast warning, however. Can this be a problem?

Comment: Listen to Eclipse and add a `@SuppressWarnings`. It is not a problem since the **runtime** check `type.isInstance(o)` guarantees that `o instanceof T`.

Answer (score 2):

With [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it's just

```
List<Apple> apples =
  Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(fruitList, Apple.class));
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: It would be cool if you posted a fragment from Guava that implements this, so we can see how the pro's do it :)

Comment: [Checked it](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/12.0/com/google/common/base/Predicates.java#437). Boils down to `type.isInstance(o)`.

Comment: Well, yes, but it's packaged up nicely in a type-safe view.

Comment: It is in fact factored to six or seven degrees of freedom :) so there's no self-contained fragment to post.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Fruit> list=new ArrayList<Fruit>();
//put some data in list here
List<Apple> sublist=new ArrayList<Apple>();
for (Fruit f:list)
    if(f instanceof Apple)  
        sublist.add((Apple)f);
```

Answer (score 0):

We created a small utility called JLinq to get similar functionality like linq in C# in java, one of them is like typeof:

```
 /**
 * @param <T> the type of the list
 * @param list the list to filter
 * @param type the desired object type that we need from these list
 * @return a new list containing only those object that from the given type 
 */
public static <T> LinkedList<T> filter(LinkedList<T> list, Class<T> type) {
    LinkedList<T> filtered = new LinkedList<T>();
    for (T object : list) {
        if (object.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            filtered.add(object);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: You are checking that `object`'s type is a **supertype** of `type`. You should be checking the opposite.

Comment: I assumed that you want everything of type `T`, which would include any subtypes.